# How to create an unscrollable grid in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, grid

@Edit
Changed the title it was missleading, sorry for that. There is a lack of research also, will try to not make the same mistake. I will keep the original question, but M123 awnser was enough, thank you.

@Original
So, Im new to Flutter, I did some udemy classes, but my knowlage is not enouth to this challenge...
I need to create an unscrollable grid, this grid must be able to hold differente types of Widgets, with differente sizes and sometimes placed in differente areas of the screen, much like a layout builder. I also must be able to save the layout.

I thought to create a matrix based in the screen size to hold the widget positions something like this:

W = Widget, X = location already taken by another widget

[image]

One of my issue here is how to print the matrix content, should I create a row inside a column, a column inside a row, use the grid view in flutter (how to?) ?

Right now I am stuck with this little code:

```
 static const String id = 'grade';
 @override
 _GradeState createState() => _GradeState();
}

class _GradeState extends State<Grade> {
 List<List<Widget>> grade = [];

 Widget _corpoDaGrade() {
   int gridStateLength = grade.length;
   double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
   double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
   double y = width / 50;
   double x = height / 50;

   print('x = $x');
   print('y = $y');
   print('width = $width');
   print('height = $height');

   for (int i = 0; i < x.toInt(); i++) {
     List<Widget> list = [];
     for (int j = 0; j < y.toInt(); j++) {
       //print(j);
       list.add(
         Container(
           height: 50,
           width: 50,
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             border: Border.all(
               color: Colors.black,
             ),
           ),
         ),
       );
     }
     grade.add(list);
   }

   return Column(
     children: [
       Expanded(
         child: Container(),
       ),
     ],
   );
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: SafeArea(
       child: _corpoDaGrade(),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

I was only trying to print the matrix with simple widgets.

I did look for some packages, like this one https://github.com/letsar/flutter_staggered_grid_view, but almost everything is scrollable and are based in lists so the widgets are placed in order, not in specific locations, maybe i missed something.

Comment: I like the edit : )     But sometimes things have to be asked that are no longer so logical afterwards.  As long as you can continue working now, it's great and if someone else has this question, they'll be happy too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use columns and rows, there is a Widget for that.

```
Table(
  children:[
    TableRow(
     children[
       ANYWDIDGET();
       ANYWDIDGET();
       ANYWDIDGET();
     ]),
    TableRow(
      children[
       ANYWDIDGET();
       ANYWDIDGET();
       ANYWDIDGET();
      ]),
  ]
); 


ANYWIDGET(){
 return...
}
```

Comment: I hate myself, I was all this time looking for grids, instead of looking at the flutter documentation x.x.  Thank you s2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it took me sometime to come back here and tell you guys which way I took to solve my issue, M123 is definitely an amazing answer and should help you, but to make it easier I found a pack in pub.dev made by Fastriver (https://github.com/organic-nailer) that creates a simple unscrollable grid view: https://pub.dev/packages/expanded_grid . Please if you use it, give him/her some love.